# Как сделать последовательность чисел 2 в n-ой степени?

Tags: python

```
def powers_of_two(n):
    i = 1
    a = []
    for x in range(n):
        a.append(i ** 2)
        i = i + 1
    return a    


print((powers_of_two(0))) #-> [1]))
print((powers_of_two(1))) #-> [1, 2])
print((powers_of_two(4))) #-> [1, 2, 4, 8, 16])
```

Последовательноть должна быть вида (#-> в коментариях в коде): [1, 2, 4, 8, 16]

Comment: очень неожиданно видеть двойку в последовательности квадратов натуральных чисел

Comment: судя по желаемому выходу интересует вывод `2` в степени до `n` включительно? Вопрос сформирован не верно. Степени двойки же нужны, а не во второй степени.

Comment: семен семеныч.... :)))

Comment: @hellog888, а вы не поделитесь, в рамках чего у вас идут все эти вопросы последние дни, чтобы отвечать поточнее? Вроде, какой-то курс зарубежный, но что вы хотите на выходе? Сертификат, знания, то и другое? (И есть ощущение, что вы выкладываете часть задач, поработав над ними, а часть - просто "на бегу").

Comment: **py.checkio.org** с этого ресурса задачи беру и с **codewars.com** там не дают сертификат (вроде), точнее я за ним и не гонюсь пытаюсь практиковаться каждый день, что бывает и ведет к некой спешке... Подскажите пожалуйста как в регулярном выражении добавить 2й аргумент? вот пишу регулярку: **b = re.findall(r'\S+', text[::-1])**, а мне нужны еще и пробелы учесть в список, они могут быть любой длины

Comment: в общем не пойму еще вопрос появился: return ' '.join(word[::-1] for word in text.split(' '))  почему если подать в функцию 'hello   world' например он ее рассплитит с учетом длины пробелов.. Почему?

Comment: Вы, когда отвечаете, @ используйте, пожалуйста. А то, если не отслеживать, то ответ не виден. Сейчас только заметил. По регуляркам не подскажу, да и лучше отдельно открыть вопрос. А с практикой хорошо, но тогда совсем на бегу лучше не надо, с этим примером вы явно почти не работали (заметна разница с другими случаями) - чужое решение не даст опыта себе. Я всегда до конца бьюсь со своими задачками:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[tio.run](https://tio.run/##dctBCsIwEEbhfU7xg5sMZmHaIiK9iYQiNKnZzIQxpXj66EZQ0PX7XnnUm3Df2hwTimxR75OkqW5imc4G0FhXZVz8OGYkUWRkhl55iZb3noIxRTNXa7/vAxFh9/rC7@7f3aH7Q4YP4jA4nBz8MbT2BA)

```
def powers_of_two(n):
  return [1<<i for i in range(n+1)]

print((powers_of_two(0))) # [1]
print((powers_of_two(1))) # [1, 2]
print((powers_of_two(4))) # [1, 2, 4, 8, 16]
```

Comment: а что значит  **1<<i**  ?

Comment: @hellog888, битовый сдвиг влево. По сути - умножение на 2 в соответствующей степени.

Comment: побитовый сдвиг влево на `i` позиций. Так можно получить все степени двойки. Ибо в битовом представлении `1,10,100,1000` соответствуют последовательности в десятичном представлении `1,2,4,8`  и так далее двигая единичку влево, получаем все требуемые степени двойки.

Comment: прикольно, спасибо за пояснение

Answer (score 1):

Если исправить код в вопросе:

а) желательно убрать лишнюю переменную,

б) надо расширить диапазон на 1 степень,

в) надо возводить не в квадрат, а в степень.

```
def powers_of_two(n):
    a = []
    for i in range(n+1):
        a.append(2**i)
    return a

print((powers_of_two(0))) #-> [1]))
print((powers_of_two(1))) #-> [1, 2])
print((powers_of_two(4))) #-> [1, 2, 4, 8, 16])
```

Comment: надо возводить не в квадрат, а в степень. lol ))) спасибо